# What is wrong with *that* question of mine?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question

Question link:

> [Why does Winforms databinding want to set my nested boolean databound property when I raise a notification event on the parent object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258232/why-does-winforms-databinding-want-to-set-my-nested-boolean-databound-property-wh)

As you can see, the question lingers in limbo with low views despite the bounty, and no one has even put a comment to tell me what is wrong with it.

So what is the problem?

- The question is clumsily written - how can I make it better?
- The question is not tagged correctly - which tags should I remove or add?
- The domain for the question (Winforms data binding) has too few experts on SO, or the question is too localized - where should I go ask that question?
- The question is too burdened with specifics that people cannot get past (IE there is a simpler question that could get more attention and still help me solve my problem) - which way should I go? (I know it is a subset of "clumsily written", but I have a feeling that that might be the case)
- There is another problem entirely - what is it?

PS: A wiki for [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) would be nice.

Comment: From my point of view your question is good: it is specific, provides decent information both with code samples and stack trace. But I cannot give you any advice on the issue. Gave you a +1 on on it though, hope that helps to draw some more attention to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is ok.

When you post a question about C-Language you get 50 views and 10 answers within 5 minutes. If you ask something specific about servers you sometimes have to wait two days and don't get a reasonable answer. So adding a bounty as you did could help.

Meanwhile I would try http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/threads/

Comment: This is really it exactly. Ironically, the question is almost _too_ specific. It's basically asking about a particular GUI library, WinForms, and a particular aspect of that library, data binding, which gives four problems: First, there are a lot of GUI libraries. Second, a lot of what used to be done with traditional GUIs is now done on the web. Third, WF is now often overshadowed by sexier sibling WPF. Fourth, only a subset of WF developers make much use of databinding. The question is good/specific, but it's borderline-niche. :/

Comment: @Nicholas Knight: Well, I wouldn't call that ironic - it is just the well-known case of a question being too specific or localized. And stacker, thank you for the link - I'll go ask my question there. (Well, on the Windows Forms data binding forums - but you get the idea.)

Comment: Hans Passant's reply has made me realize that there may be more to it than "too localized" - I have unaccepted your answer in order to encourage feedback a little longer. Thank you for understanding.

Answer (score 4):

Being the [winforms] pope, I got some feedback here.  There are certain tags you want to avoid if you want to encourage views.  In particular [databinding] and [datagridview] have stigma.  They are the [vb6] tags of winforms.  I don't look at the questions tagged with them, I see few other contributors do either.  There aren't that many to start with, winforms isn't exactly sexy anymore.

Not so sure this actually will work, your question is in fact about data-binding.  But if you don't get the views, the odds for an answer are slim by design.  The bounty should help.

Comment: Why would such a stigma exist? Is it historic? (all these questions were VB6 questions so it has taken to imply that even though both [databinding] and [datagridview] are applicable to .NET) Is it because the "databinding" method of programming is only used by former VB6 programmers? Another reason? I would like to understand what you mean.

Comment: I don't want to step on any toes, it isn't specific to vb6 programmers.  More the kind of programmers that dump tens of thousands of records in a grid and declare the job done.  Then come to SO when the customer complains.

Comment: Ah. A method of programming that is easy to pick up and thus often misused. I can understand why people wouldn't want to read questions with that tag.

Answer (score 3):

Because approximately 3.14 people in North America program winforms?

Comment: Great, now I want pie.